# project builds in VS, but not with msbuild, error with obj\Debug\TempPE\My Project.Resources.Designer.vb.dll

Tags: asp.net, msbuild

I've got a dot.net 3.5 app that builds fine within visual studio, but when I manually build via MSbuild, it throws the following error:

```
error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\TempPE\My Project.Resources.Designer.vb.dll
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

I found this in my project file

```
<Content Include="obj\Debug\TempPE\My Project.Resources.Designer.vb.dll" />
```

I'm assuming it'd be a bad idea to just remove this?

If I compile it in visual studio,  I look under obj/debug/TempPE and the directory is empty.

Comment: Old question but here's a possible solution. Do Rebuild all.